# Clickable Links on event title inside Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to place a link inside my fullcalendar events, but it's not working...

It should work like this: All event must have a trigger for eventClick (its working ok). Inside the event.title it must have a link for different url.

Using eventRender I've placed the link inside event.title but eventClick is overlapping it and I just get the click action for it.

How does the link inside event.title works correctly??

Comment: You haven't provided any code or proper description of the problem, so it would be impossible to correct your code. In future when asking questions please provide clear descriptions and also a relevant code sample, so we can understand clearly :-).

Comment: However, regardless of that I can suggest a different approach anyway: if you want the user to go to a specific URL when the event is clicked, then just set the `url` property in the event data, as per the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) . No need to use the title, or anything to do with eventClick.